# How to programmatically Mute/Silent devices running Lollipop?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

How I can make my phone mute in lollipop devices programmatically? For pre-lollipop devices, it can be done pretty well using `AudioManager` class but In android 5.0 and above, the device can be kept on Vibrate mode but I am not able to mute it. Can anyone help me out that how can we programmatically change phone's volume modes between NONE, PRIORITY and ALL?

Thanks.

Comment: I read [this](https://www.androidpit.com/android-5-0-lollipop-silent-mode) and is that the problem? Lollipop has no 0 volume option?

Answer (score 2):

use this code:

```
final AudioManager mode = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

and give this permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

i tried it on android 5.0.1 in an onclick event. it sets phone in priority then triggering the onclick again will place the phone in no interruption.

Comment: doing this will put phone in only Vibrate mode for lollipop devices!!

Comment: in xiaomi devices doing this will put phone in Vibrate mode for devices!!

Comment: For newer devices, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39152607/2523007

Comment: not working for me on xiaomi it silent both playing video and ringer.I want to silent only phone ring not video volume any idea how to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Replace RINGER_MODE_SILENT with RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE

```
AudioManager audiomanage = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audiomanage.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
```