# Android N: checking for DND state changed before updating checkbox preference

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-preferences, android-audiomanager, android-7.0-nougat

My app sets the ringer mode to silent but with Android N I get a `java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to change Do Not Disturb state`.

I followed the steps from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39151453/in-android-7-api-level-24-my-app-is-not-allowed-to-mute-phone-set-ringer-mode) and the following code will open an activity which contains a toggle button for enabling the permission to change the ringer mode. This activity can be "backed" from without the enabling of the permission.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
                        android.provider.Settings
                        .ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);

    startActivity(intent);
```

The problem is that I want to ensure that the permission is granted before attempting to use the silent ringer mode functionality.

I'm adding a CheckBoxPreference to enable and disable of this ringer mode toggling. So if the checkbox is checked, I can set the ringer mode to silent and if it's not, I will not change the ringer mode.

Until now I managed to start this permission request when the user clicks the checkbox:

```
disableSoundCheckboxPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(
                new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {
...
// check for Android N and start the activity mentioned above
```

But what is the correct way to enable this checkbox only if the permission was granted? I guess it should have something to do with `ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_GRANTED_CHANGED`and a listener but I would need some ideas to implement this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this and will post the answer in case someone else needs it.

A BroadcastListener is not needed in this case. You just need to request the permission when the user first clicks on the preference with an `OnPreferenceClickListener`:

```
private void requestNotificationPolicyAccess() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N && !isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.
                    ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
```

If the user grants the permission, when he will click again, you will allow the user to change the state of the `CheckBox`. If the permission is not granted, you will continue updating the `CheckBox` with "false" and maybe write in it's `android:summary` that permission must be granted first. You can verify with:

```
private boolean isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()  {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    return notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted();
}
```