# How do I listen for user grant or denial of Do Not Disturb permission?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I want to request ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY permission from the user, so I used the following code:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
                && !notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
            //Permission not granted so we will ask for it.
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.Settings
                            .ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);

            //did the user allow the Don't Disturb  permission or just ignore it?

        } else {
            //Permission granted

        }
```

But how do I listen for user grant or denial of this request? maybe he didn't allow the DND permission, how do I know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity` as the following:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = 
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert notificationManager != null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
                && !notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
            //Permission not granted so we will ask for it.
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 55);
        } else {
            //Permission was granted          
        }
```

then I checked the result in `onActivityResult` using `isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()`

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 55) {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplication().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                assert mNotificationManager != null;
                if (mNotificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
                    //DND permission is granted 
                    //do something 
                }else{
                    //DND permission isn't granted 
                    //request the permission again or do something else 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this worked for me but I don't know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Android Request App](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#make-the-request). There is example with comment to help you understand.

You did the first part which is ask for permission, then you have to handle the response with `onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults)`

You can write something like this:

```java
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplication().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (mNotificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
            Log.d("POLICY_PERMISSION", "DND permission granted for Phone.");
        } else {
            Log.d("POLICY_PERMISSION", "DND permission not granted for Phone.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: but ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY permission is different, to ask this permission we open a setting screen for the user using intent, I didn't call `requestPermissions()`.

Comment: Use [ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_GRANTED_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_GRANTED_CHANGED) to listen for user grant or denial of this access.

Comment: I want to use  ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_GRANTED_CHANGED but how? :(

Comment: If you don't need to, why use it ? Here is another post with similar needs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39732880/android-n-checking-for-dnd-state-changed-before-updating-checkbox-preference

Comment: In his case he don't need to use it because he has `OnPreferenceClickListener`, but in my case I need it. And about the`onRequestPermissionsResult`, it works only with permissions that requested via `requestPermissions()`, but the DND permission is not.

Comment: I tried to use `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)`, then I checked the result in `onActivityResult` using `isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()`, it worked, but I have another permission which handled using `onRequestPermissionsResult`, now how to check for both of them (T-T).

Comment: Keep a boolean to know if the user granted your first permission and do the same for the second, and check if both are true to move on

Comment: Yes I did this, but where do I check? I tried to check them inside `onCreate()` after the code of requesting, but the checking code ran before reaching the result.

Comment: Is it possible to check thoses variables just before you call the function that needs to use this service ?

Comment: I want to check the variables then if both of them true I will call the function which needs these permissions.

Comment: You can maybe use `sharedPreferences` for that I don't know if it's optimal but it'll do the job

Comment: I used two other flags, when `onRequestPermissionsResult` called the flag1 will be true, and when `onActivityResult` called the flag2 will be true, then inside `onResume()` I checked if both flags are true that means I got the two permissions result, then I checked for permissions flag if both true then I will start my function. Thank you very much for helping me