# Android - make phone silent for a limited amounts of time (dyanmically)

Tags: java, android, silent-notification

I want  to put my phone on silent mode for a shorter amount of time.

I am using the following code to put my phone on silent mode and it works. However the next segment doesn't put it back to ringer mode/previous mode.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            // turn off beep sounds
                mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true);
                mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, true);
                mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
                mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, true);
                mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
        }
```

This to put it back on previous state:

```
    public void destroy()
{
        mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, false);
        mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, false);
        mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
        mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, false);
        mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, false);


    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy"); }
```

I tested by exiting the app also by manually calling those codes in onDestory on a seperate methode but got no success,it stays silent.

It will be better if I can put my phone on silent mode for a small amounts of time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Create an [Alarm](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) using `AlarmManager` when you want to put your
  phone to Silent Mode [make your device silent that time](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/07/19/how-to-set-your-android-phone-in-silent-mode-or-vibrate-mode-or-normal-mode-programatically/)
- Assign time in `AlarmManager` when you want to stop it. [Receive](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver) the
  alarm using `BroadcastReceiver` and stop the silent Mode.

Have a look on this [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280319/using-alarmmanager-to-activate-and-deactivate-silence-mode)