# Android 8: Can't change ringer mode to non-silent when ringer mode is silent

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-broadcastreceiver

I wrote an Android application, that changes the ringer mode from any mode to normal, if a BroadcastReceiver receives a notification.

**It's working fine on Android < 8.**

It also works for my Android 8 device, if **ringer mode != silent** when the broadcast receiver reacts.

- ringer mode != silent & change it to any ringer mode

  - works on all devices
- ringer mode == silent & change it to silent mode

  - works fine on all devices
- ringer mode == silent & change it to non-silent mode

  - works only on older devices with Android < 8

When changing from silent to non-silent on Android 8, I get an exception saying `Boradcast already finished`?!

This behavior is only on my Android 8 device, older devices work fine.

Can someone help on this strange behavior? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the issue: It's caused by the "Do not disturb" mode in newer Android versions.

To disable this silent-mode you have to

1. add permission to AndroidManifest:

   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"
2. Ask the user to allow to leave this do-not-disturb mode by the following intent:

   Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
   startActivity(intent);

See also this question/answer: [In Android 7 (API level 24) my app is not allowed to mute phone (set ringer mode to silent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39151453/in-android-7-api-level-24-my-app-is-not-allowed-to-mute-phone-set-ringer-mode)