# App gets crashed after I added audio manager in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an app which sets ringer mode to silent from vibrate or normal mode, I checked the code much time but not able to find the problem in my code. Hope community will find the problem. And Help me to resolve.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AudioManager myAudioManager;
    private Button silentBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        silentBtn = findViewById(R.id.button);

        myAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        silentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int mod = myAudioManager.getRingerMode();
                if (mod == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have wasted your time by clicking this Button.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();

                } else {
                    myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You are Good to Go.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast1.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I expect that the app should not crash when I click the button.

Comment: post your error  log

Comment: The error log contains many characters. Please wait I'm sending you error log in parts.

Comment: 2019-06-13 23:31:54.653 31198-31216/? E/LB: fail to open file: No such file or directory
2019-06-13 23:31:55.560 31198-31198/com.abhishakkrmalviya.audioprofilechange E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.abhishakkrmalviya.audioprofilechange, PID: 31198
    java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to change Do Not Disturb state
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1953)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1921)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1871)

Comment: at android.media.IAudioService$Stub$Proxy.setRingerModeExternal(IAudioService.java:1328)
        at android.media.AudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.java:1146)
        at com.abhishakkrmalviya.audioprofilechange.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:34)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6614)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6591)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:786)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25948)

Comment: at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)

Comment: Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
        at com.android.server.audio.AudioService.setRingerModeExternal(AudioService.java:2605)
        at android.media.IAudioService$Stub.onTransact(IAudioService.java:247)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:733)

Comment: Any reason why you’re setting the toast to a variable which is never used after it is shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add this permission in manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"
```

Comment: Still Getting Crashed. ~`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>` I have added this one too. Just to check.

Comment: you have to check self permission  android version if > lolipop  see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39152607/8660721

Comment: The `<uses-permission>` tag should be self-closing.