# Unable to play mp3 in android pie (9)

Tags: android

Below code is working till Oreo but same code is not working in android pie. Please check my code.

```
int audioFile = R.raw.ring;
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
try {

    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this,
            Uri.parse("android.resource://com.blh.pickupfresh.resturentapp/" + audioFile));

    final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING),0);
    mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
    mMediaPlayer.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work? does it throw any exceptions?

Comment: It is working till oreo but not working in android pie

Comment: `and resolve the same asap` stackoverflow does not work this way. If you want something ASAP - you can post a project on some freelance service, and get a developer to help you ASAP for money

Comment: `It is working till oreo but not working in android pie` that's what you wrote in question, but `Why doesn't it work?` in pie? what fails?  `does it throw any exceptions?`

Comment: Yes it is working till oreo but not working in android 9 and also I am not getting any exception

Comment: doesn't `e.printStackTrace();` print any exceptions? Are you sure?

Comment: yes I am not getting

Comment: In the log lso I am getting any exception

Comment: Checked the code on Pie....Working fine and the file is played....Please check DoNotDisturb is turned off.

Comment: don't disturb mode is turned off in my phone but not working when my media and ringtone volume is slient

Comment: ok, then probably the problem is not in playing MP3, but in setting volume of `AudioManager.STREAM_RING`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
int audioFile = R.raw.ring;

if(mMediaPlayer == null)
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

try {
    final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                .setLegacyStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
                .build());
    } else {
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }

    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() 
      {
          @Override
          public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
               mp.start();
          }
      });

    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.blh.pickupfresh.resturentapp/" + audioFile));
    mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e(TAG,"ERROR=" + e.getMessage());
}
```

Here I have used `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC` and also increased volume for the same stream. It will play sound even in Silent mode OR DND.

**UPDATE:** For Android 9 in some device `mMediaPlayer.prepare()` takes seconds, so we should use async method with callback and its working.

---

In android (at least oreo + pie), When **Silent mode is ON** OR **DND mode is ON** we can not set `AudioManager.STREAM_RING` to NORMAL because it will throw an Exception

`java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to change Do Not Disturb state`.
See this for further details [In Android 7 (API level 24) my app is not allowed to mute phone (set ringer mode to silent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39151453/in-android-7-api-level-24-my-app-is-not-allowed-to-mute-phone-set-ringer-mode)

Comment: On which device you are trying?? And when the file is not played (try with normal,silent and dnd mode)?? Pls let me know.

Comment: MI A2 Normal mode it is working but when my mobile is in slient and dnd mode ten not working'

Comment: if my phone lock then I will get ring

Comment: it's working but not able to get ring when phone is lock

Comment: So when you want to play this sound??

Comment: @AvinashKarn Check my updated answer. and let me know the result

Comment: its working but when my phone screen is lock then ring is not coming

Comment: when my screen is lock alarm volume is increasing but not getting ring

Comment: when I got notification then I need to play unlimited ring whether phone is lock or unlock and phone is slient mode then also need to play song. I have checked with different version when phone is lock then I got ring till Nougout after Nougout not able to get ring in lock mode. but my media volume is increasing when phone is locked but ring is not comming