# Flutter - Is there a way to mute a phone with an app?

Tags: flutter, maps, mute

I've started with Flutter and I´m currently working on a project which allows the application to mute the phone if you´re at a specified position. I´ve implemented Google Maps etc. Everything works except that the marker isn´t visible but that´s another question. My question is how I can mute the phone with an app. I didn´t find a solution  anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt that Flutter provides such a fuctionality out of the box. I suggest searching 3rd party packages for it. If that fails you can implement this feature nativly on each platform using [Platform Channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39151453/in-android-7-api-level-24-my-app-is-not-allowed-to-mute-phone-set-ringer-mode/39152607#39152607) you can find how to achieve this on Android, and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284402/how-to-disable-ios-system-sounds/) how to do it on IOS.

Answer (score 0):

### There are 2 plugins avelable for this

1. **sound_mode**: https://pub.dev/packages/sound_mode

Features,

- Detect device's current sound mode (both IOS & Android)
- Able to toggle between Normal, Silent & Vibrate mode (only Android)
- Grant Do No Disturb permissions for devices above platform version
  Android 6.0 (API 23) (only Android)

---

2. **flutter_mute**: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mute

Features,

- Detect device current ringer mode
- Able to toggle between Normal, Silent & Vibrate mode (Only for
  Android)
- Grant notification policy access for devices above platform version
  Android 7.0 (API 24)

> Both Pulgins can toggle your Android base device (Not IOS device)

---

Example(Android),

```
import 'package:sound_mode/utils/ringer_mode_statuses.dart';

// Handle Platform Exceptions for devices running above Android 6.0 
try {
  await SoundMode.setSoundMode(RingerModeStatus.silent);
} on PlatformException {
  print('Please enable permissions required');
}
```

Example(ISO):

```
RingerModeStatus ringerStatus = RingerModeStatus.unknown;

// The one second delay is needed to get accurate results on IOS...
Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () async {
  try {
    ringerStatus = await SoundMode.ringerModeStatus;
  } catch (err) {
    ringerStatus = RingerModeStatus.unknown;
  }
  print(ringerStatus);
});
```