# Code examples with 'context.' do not work when I paste them

Tags: android-context

Hi I am a novice Java and Android programmer and apologies if this is a bit of a dumb question.

I have seen many examples recently where the top voted solution includes code that will not resolve/run when i cut and paste it into my code.

My main issue is that I cannot work out how to change 'context.' given in the example below to something that will run.

As an example

I get this error ...

```
/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dummies.silentmodetoggle, PID: 12988
    java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to change Do Not Disturb state
        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2285)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2269)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2252)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2194)
        at android.media.IAudioService$Stub$Proxy.setRingerModeExternal(IAudioService.java:2835)
        at android.media.AudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.java:1150)
        at com.dummies.silentmodetoggle.util.RingerHelper.performToggle(RingerHelper.java:20)
        at com.dummies.silentmodetoggle.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:41)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7350)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7327)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:807)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28166)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7464)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:955)
     Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
        at com.android.server.audio.AudioService.setRingerModeExternal(AudioService.java:3169)
        at android.media.IAudioService$Stub.onTransact(IAudioService.java:1257)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1138)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1102)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12988 SIG: 9

The Solution is in:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39151453/in-android-7-api-level-24-my-app-is-not-allowed-to-mute-phone-set-ringer-mode#

When I cut and paste this code in:

    NotificationManager notificationManager = 
        (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
        && !notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(
                            android.provider.Settings
                            .ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

many of the parts do not initially work but after importing a few classes most of the issues go away apart from:

context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); where it can't work out what to use for context

and 

startActivity(intent); where it cannot find the class or what to use for intent.
```

As an aside, I am not looking for an answer to the Notification issue, I am after help with understanding how do I successfully take Stack overflow code paste it into my code and work out where the missing parts come from, particularly 'context.'.

I am working through a few different Android learning books including Android App Development for Dummies which is where this example is from. I have got the code to work by using an emulator with Lollipop code as this predates the introduction of the newish DND functionality.

Finally, I am trying to get it straight in my head how to use the reference guide as I come from a mainframe background where they seem to use a different way of explaining things.

All help gratefully received

Cheers
Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right so I have dug a little and get it now.

'context.' is generic and can b replaced in this instance with this.getBaseContext().

Here is the code example.

```
private void updateUI() {
        // Find the view named phone_icon in our layout. We know it's
        // an ImageView in the layout , so downcast it to an ImageView.
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.phone_icon);

        NotificationManager notificationManager;
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
                && !notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.Settings
                            .ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
```